# Why are "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'ViewSwitcher'"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-5, viewswitcher

I have an MVC 5 based solution, with a `Client` and `Data` project. It includes the partial `_ViewSwitcher` as I want to serve mobile and desktop browsers. On the home page, when I click the ViewSwitcher's `Mobile view` link, I get the following exception:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'ViewSwitcher'....

The request for 'ViewSwitcher' has found the following matching controllers:
PayCaddy.Data.Controllers.ViewSwitcherController
PayCaddy.Client.Controllers.ViewSwitcherController
```

I have done a solution wide search on all files for the term (not whole word) `'ViewSwitcher', and found only one .cs result, in the`.Client`project, and three results in`_Layout.Mobile.cshtml`and`_ViewSwitcher.cshtml`. Plus I have manually checked the file system for any duplicate and found none.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Weird! What else have you tried? Did you clear the bin of possible old assemblies? Is this the only solution hosted on the server/service?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ViewSwitcher so this may be a silly question. When you added it to your solution, did you add it to both projects? And if so, is that necessary?

Comment: Yes. The data project was oiginsally the whole project, and when I ended up with only one view, and tons of data modelling, I moved the client stuff into its own project. Yet I've cleared the data project's bin folders and even manually searched the data project's `.csproj` file for the duplicate View Switcher and I can't find it anywhere. I didn't add it myself, it was part of some NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `Client` was referencing an old DLL of `Data`, not the `Data` project, i.e. it was an 'assembly reference' instead of a 'project reference'. Deleting the old DLL, and switching the reference to a project reference did the trick. But, not before I had to remove all `using` statements for `Data`, rebuild and get errors, and then replace all the `using`s. Now all is working fine.